# XCode - Creating method stubs automatically?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode4

Is it possible to get xcode to generate the method stubs for the methods that you define in your header file? I'm not talking about protocol methods but your own custom methods in your class.

Cheers

Comment: I've added objective-c as a tag, because I am looking for a c++ answer to this question. If this is not Objective-C that this is talking about, please correct my tag to the correct language. Surely it is not c++ (whilst I am using XCode).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe Xcode does not have a command to generate stubs for all (or all unimplemented) methods.  However, you can have Xcode generate at least the method signature per method.

If you define, for example, the following method declarations:

```
- (void)aVoidMethod;
- (int)aMethodReturningInt;
- (CGSize)sizeOfSomething;

+ (void)classMethod;
+ (NSString *)stringClassMethod;
```

you can generate the method signatures by putting the appropriate sign (`+`/`-`) [I forgot the term :) ] plus the first few characters per method.

For example:

- Type `- av` (case insensitive) and CodeSense will automatically (most likely) choose `- (void)aVoidMethod`
- `+ cl` to generate method signature for `+ (void)classMethod`
- and so on. This also works for methods with any number of parameters.

Comment: I think you forgot to finish your answer.

Comment: @jrturton Thanks for pointing that out. My internet connection got intermittent when I posted my answer. I had to refresh the page, posted the answer because there was still text on the text box, but did not bother to check if it was complete. :)

Comment: @neilvillareal Yep, that's the approach that I'm currently using, but if you have a large number of methods in your class you have to keep going back and forth to check which one is next, or you can copy all the method declarations into the implementation file as a starting point. Both ways are rather tedious. It would be nice if you could just right click a selection of methods and choose 'create method stubs' maybe from within the refactor menu.

Comment: @JacobJoz I agree with you. That is one feature of Eclipse that I would like to get in Xcode.